# Detect navigation key press in datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I tried with keypress event of datagridview, but it was not working. How can I detect the up-down-left-right arrow key presses in datagridview?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `KeyDown` event:

```
private void dgv1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up || e.KeyCode == Keys.Down || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
         //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: tried to do that, but it is not working properly. An item is only selected after keypress and not after keydown, so cannot get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with `PreviewKeyDown`:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());

    dgv.Rows.Add("text");

    dgv.PreviewKeyDown += (sender, args) =>
    {
        Debug.Print(args.KeyCode.ToString());
    };
}
```